# Is it possible to use CSS flex to make the video element width always 50% of its container?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to use CSS flex to make the video element width always 50% of its container width?

Here is my code.

```js
function go() {
  let cell2 = document.getElementById("cell2");
  let trouble = document.getElementById("trouble");
  let htmlString = "<div class=\"border border-dark m-1 p-0 rounded-3 peer-cell text-break\">";
  htmlString += "<video className=\"m-0 p-0 rounded-3\" controls autoplay muted>";
  htmlString += "<source src=\"https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4\">";
  htmlString += "</video>";
  htmlString += "</div>";
  let p = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(htmlString);

  trouble.insertBefore(p, cell2);
}
```

```css
video {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.peer-cell {
  background-color: red;
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.peer {
  height: 200px;
  margin: 3px;
  width: calc(100% - 6px);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="h-100 m-0 overflow-auto p-0 w-100">
  <div class="d-flex flex-row peer" id="trouble">
    <div id="cell2" class="border border-dark m-1 p-1 rounded-3 peer-cell text-break">
      Peer Name:sdff<br/>Status:connected
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="go()">Switch</button>
```

When I click on the button, suppose a video element would be added to a div whose id is "trouble"; and both the video element and the "cell2" width should be equal to 50% of its parent.

Unfortunately, it does not work as my expectation, both the video element and the "cell2" width are not equal to 50% of its parent.

Would you tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#cell2 {
width: 3vw; 
}
.video {
width: 3vw;
}
```

This worked for me, you will get your desired output:

**PC and Mobile Screens:**
[image: PC]
[image: Mobile Screen]

**Check output:**

```js
function go() {
        let cell2 = document.getElementById("cell2");
        let trouble = document.getElementById("trouble");

        let htmlString = "<div class=\"border border-dark m-1 p-0 rounded-3 peer-cell text-break video\">";
        htmlString += "<video className=\"m-0 p-0 rounded-3\" controls autoplay muted>";
        htmlString += "<source src=\"https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4\">";
        htmlString += "</video>";
        htmlString += "</div>";
        let p = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(htmlString);

        trouble.insertBefore(p, cell2);
    }
```

```css
    video {
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .peer-cell {
        background-color: red;
        flex-grow: 1;
        position: relative;
    }

    .peer {
        height: 200px;
        margin: 3px;
        width: calc(100% - 6px);
    }
    #cell2 {
        width: 3vw;
        color: #fff;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000;
        font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
    .video {
        width: 3vw;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="h-80 m-0 p-0 w-100 center">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row peer" id="trouble">
        <div id="cell2" class="border border-dark m-1 p-1 rounded-3 peer-cell text-break">
            Peer Name:sdff<br />Status:connected
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<center>
    <button onclick="go()">Switch</button>
</center>
```

Comment: Would you tell me how it works?

Comment: Why the `div` width set to 3% width of the viewport work?

Comment: It's like both div's widths should be equal as the parent div is already having 100% width of the webpage.

Comment: When I click more than one time, those divs are the same width, it strange. Even if I set it to 100vw, it also works properly, I want to know why.